# generating a string from database values in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-1.3

i have a table called merchants in my database, in that table i have the field named merchant_code, and i want to generate a 8 code for my field in such a way that the first two characters contains the first two letters from my state_name from states table and next two characters contains first two letters from my city_name from cities table, and the last four characters should contain digits starting from ooo1.
at the time of adding the merchant i want this code to automatically add, and save in my database 
i'm a beginner in cakehp, so please give me answer briefly, would be thankful if i found the solution

Answer (score 2):

Merchant model is probably associated with City model (as belongsTo), which in turn is associated with State model (belongsTo as well). You can create an afterSave callback for your  Merchant model and check the argument $created. If its true, just fetch 2 records from associated models and compose your merchant_code. Something like this: (considering you use Containable behavior for your City model):

```
public function afterSave($created) {
    parent::afterSave($created);
    if ($created) {
        $this->City->contain('State');
        $names = $this->City->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'City.id' => $this->data['Merchant']['city_id']
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                'City.city_name',
                'State.state_name',
            )
        ));

        if (!empty($names)) {
            $merchant_code = substr($names['State']['state_name'], 0, 2)
                . substr($names['City']['city_name'], 0, 2)
                . sprintf('%1$04d', $this->getLastInsertID());
            $this->saveField('merchant_code', $merchant_code);
        }
    }
}
```